# How to automatically multiline a TextInput value after a long input from a user?

Tags: react-native

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwljx.jpg)

I am currently starting with a simple calculator and understanding the basics of React-native however I find myself stuck. I have researched that `adjustsFontSizeToFit` is currently not available for `android` and I want my `TextInput` to show all the numbers that the user inputs from start to last (as you can see in the screenshot, only 12 numbers can be seen but I put more than 12 numbers there)

*Note : Please ignore the button in the screenshot as I have yet to tackle more things about that*

code :

ANS

```
  <View style = {{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'flex-start'} }>
    <TextInput 
    style = {one.inputText1}
    placeholder = {" Please input \n the first \n number  here."}
    placeholderTextColor = '#66FCF1'
    onChangeText = { this.handleChangedText }
    keyboardType = 'numeric'
    > 
    </TextInput>

    <TextInput
     style = {one.inputText2}
     placeholder = { "Please input \n the second \n number  here." }
     placeholderTextColor = '#EDF5E1'
     onChangeText = { this.handleChangedText2 }
     keyboardType = 'numeric'
    >  
    </TextInput>
  </View>
```

style :

```
 const one = StyleSheet.create({

 txtDefault: {
 flex: 0.2, 
 backgroundColor: 'white', 
 alignItems: 'center', 
 justifyContent:'center', 
 fontSize: 30, 
 textAlign: 'center',
 textAlignVertical: 'center',
 borderColor: 'black',
 borderWidth: 1,
 fontWeight: 'bold',
 color: '#242582',

 },

 inputText1: {
 backgroundColor: '#0B0C10', 
 alignItems: 'center', 
 justifyContent:'center', 
 fontSize: 30, 
 textAlign: 'center',
 textAlignVertical: 'center',
 width: 210,
 height: 570,
 fontWeight: 'bold',
 color: '#66FCF1',
 },

 inputText2: {
 backgroundColor: '#1F2833',  
 alignItems: 'center', 
 justifyContent:'center', 
 fontSize: 30, 
 textAlign: 'center',
 textAlignVertical: 'center',
 width: 210,
 height: 570,
 fontWeight: 'bold',
 color: '#45A29E',
 },
```

Comment: Can you please post some of your code?

Comment: well my codes is just for the layouts ...@getumangon

Comment: I added the multi line code in there and it still does not show all the input of the user

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is that you have given `keyboardType="numeric"`

**keyboardType** doesn't work well with **multiline**

Try omitting **keyboardType**